# Transfer Data between cgi and Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, perl, cgi

I want to transfer Data between the cgi page and javascript/Jquery and return back to cgi page

Index.html has the form contents

login.cgi has

```
my $username= $cgi->param('uid');
if (($cgi->param('uid') eq 'demo') && ($cgi->param('pwd') eq 'demo')) {
my $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=> 'uid', -value=> $cgi->param('uid'));
print $cgi->redirect(-uri => '/cgi-bin/index.cgi', -cookie => $cookie);
```

index.cgi has

```
my $uid = $cookies{uid}->value;
print $uid;
print <<"HTML_CODE"
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/test_javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2> This is a Demo Login Page of $uid </h2>
</body>
</html>
HTML_CODE
;
```

test_javascript.js has

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var uid = $('#uid').attr('value');
 if (uid) {
 $.ajax({
   url:'/cgi-bin/index.cgi',
   data: "uid=" + uid,
   // script call was *not* successful
        error: function() { 
            alert("script call was not successful");
        },
        // script call was successful 
        // data should contain the string returned by the Perl script 
         success: function(data){
            alert("Your userid is: " + data)
        }
     });
}

 }
)
```

Comment: the `var uid = $('#uid').attr('value');` should do what? (mean in the context of your html).

Comment: I am just learning javascript, Can you tell me how do i transfer data between index.cgi and test_javascript.js

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var uid = $.cookie("uid");
 if (uid) {
 $.ajax({
   url:'/cgi-bin/index.cgi',
   data: "uid=" + uid,
   // script call was *not* successful
        error: function() { 
            alert("script call was not successful");
        },
        // script call was successful 
        // data should contain the string returned by the Perl script 
         success: function(data){
            alert("Your userid is: " + data)
        }
     });
}

 }
)
```

Comment: Actually i want to have the value of uid from index.cgi in the test_javascript so that i can use it for others

Comment: In this case just read the cookie in JS instead of Perl. I changed my answer.

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function over var uid = $.cookie("uid");

Answer (score 0):

Otion 1 - I would hardcode it in the index.cgi. This way you can insert the value into the javascript code.

This should be your index.cgi:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var uid = $cookies{uid}->value;
 if (uid) {
 $.ajax({
   url:'/cgi-bin/index.cgi',
   data: "uid=" + uid,
   // script call was *not* successful
        error: function() { 
            alert("script call was not successful");
        },
        // script call was successful 
        // data should contain the string returned by the Perl script 
         success: function(data){
            alert("Your userid is: " + data)
        }
     });
}

 }
)
    my $uid = $cookies{uid}->value;
    print $uid;
    print <<"HTML_CODE"
    <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/test_javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2> This is a Demo Login Page of $uid </h2>
    </body>
    </html>
    HTML_CODE
    ;
```

Option 2 - assign $cookies{uid}->value to a hidden input and have testjavascript pick it up later

Index.cgi:

```
print <<"HTML_CODE"
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/test_javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2> This is a Demo Login Page of $uid </h2>
<input id="uid" type="$cookie{uid}->value"/>
</body>
</html>
HTML_CODE
;
```

Comment: I am using this alert in the javascript just to get the value of uid. I have a javascript which determines if a uid is admin or not. I can get the uid from document.search but dont want to use document.search since it will show uid in the url. So i have the value of uid from the form in the cgi. I just want to get that uid value in javascript so that i can compare uid and tell if its an admin in the test_javascript.js

Comment: so basically you're saying you don't want to have uid visble on your page source? that's why you're trying to pass it to your JS during run time? Then the answer is no. there's no easy. What you could do is have your cgi generate a dynamic JS script, inserted UID in it(via write text file) and then you reference it from your CGI page.

Comment: I can have the uid as hidden but in the test_javascript.js i want to get the value of the uid from cgi as var uid = demo or something... I think it can be done with simple javascript but i am so new on javascript, i couldnt think of any process

Comment: Using cookie has its downfalls. browser with cookies disabled will cause issue to your pages. Also, you do know cookies information can be viewed just as simple as the data in your hmtl source?